# Why are Abby and Gibbs so attached?

Tags: ncis

I recently started watching *NCIS* season 9 to 10, but having never seen it before I can't help but wonder, do we ever find out why Abby and Gibbs are so attached?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abby_Sciuto#Leroy_Jethro_Gibbs

Comment: Thank you i ve read this but still why is their relationship like that? What actually connects them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Gibbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leroy_Jethro_Gibbs) lost his daughter

> eight-year-old daughter Kelly, was murdered by a Mexican drug dealer

And Abby became her replacement

> Abby, who he views like a daughter

Their relationship is describe in [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abby_Sciuto#Leroy_Jethro_Gibbs)

> Gibbs is depicted as having a close (father/daughter-like) relationship with Abby

Relationship is two sided

> Abby is fiercely loyal to the team, and considers them family